# Protractor: How to use browser.sleep inside of element.all(locator).each(eachFunction)

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Expecting: elem[0] text to print, sleep, elem[1] text to print, sleep, etc...

Actual: is printing out the text for each element then executing browser.sleep once at the end.

Once I get this working I would like to actually click on each link and assert a corresponding profile page is loaded.

I should also mention that I have SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false and am using mocha

```
    describe.only('clicking each user in the list', () => {
        it('should display the correct profile page', async () => {
            await element.all(by.repeater('user in currentNode.children')).each(async (elem)=> {
                console.log(await elem.getText())
                await browser.sleep(5000)
            });
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this did the trick

```
    describe.only('clicking each user in the list', () => {
        it('should display the correct profile page', async () => {
            const elements = await element.all(by.repeater('user in currentNode.children'));

            for (const element of elements) {
                const text = await element.getText()
                await browser.sleep(1000)
                console.log(text)
            }
```